# Make a term appear in my solution

Tags: simplifying-expressions, system

There is a solution for a linear system:

```
F1 = dpdx + Sin[θ]/Fr^2
F2 = dpdx + Χ*Sin[θ]/(Fr^2) 

solve = Solve[{C2 == 0, Re1*(F1*1/2 + B1 + C1) == 0, 
   Re1*(F1*h^2/2 + B1*h + C1) == Re1/η*(F2*h^2/2 + B2*h + C2), 
   Re1*(F1*h + B1) == Re1/η*(F2*h + B2)}, {B1, B2, C1, C2}]

In[90]:= B1 = solve[[1, 1, 2]] // FullSimplify

Out[90]= -((dpdx Fr^2 (h^2 (-1 + η) + η) + (η + h^2 η - 
h^2 Χ) Sin[θ])/(2 Fr^2 η))

In[91]:= B2 = solve[[1, 2, 2]] // FullSimplify

Out[91]= -((dpdx Fr^2 ((-2 + h) h (-1 + η) + η) + ((-1 + h)^2 η - (-2 
+ h) h Χ) Sin[θ])/(2 Fr^2))

In[39]:= C1 = solve[[1, 3, 2]] // FullSimplify

Out[39]= (h^2 (dpdx Fr^2 (-1 + η) + (η - Χ) Sin[θ]))/(2 Fr^2 η)

In[40]:= C2 = 0

Out[40]= 0
```

There is a way to substitute in the solution `(ηh - η - h)-> m`?
If it's not possible, maybe substitute `(-h^2 + h^2η + η)-> m`?

Comment: Did you try `ηh -> m + η + h` ?

Comment: Yes.. doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[solve[[1, 1, 2]],  {-h^2 + h^2 η + η == m}] // TeXForm
```

> $\frac{h^2 (X-1) \sin (\theta )-m \left(\text{dpdx} \text{Fr}^2+\sin (\theta )\right)}{2
>    \text{Fr}^2 \eta }$

```
FullSimplify[solve[[1, 2, 2]], {-h^2 + h^2 η + η == m}] // TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{\text{dpdx} \text{Fr}^2 (m-2 (\eta -1) h)+\sin (\theta ) (h (-2 \eta +h (-X)+h+2 X)+m)}{2
>    \text{Fr}^2}$